# Вопрос с доступом к файлам

Tags: windows, доступ

В корпоративной сети есть программка в которой анализируется скорость печати. Данная программа создаёт файлы с юзерами и записывает в них все изменения.
Решили провести конкурс на скорость. Выявилась проблема не защищённости файлов от правки.  При блокировании доступа к файлам программа тестирования отказывается работать.
Прошу подсказать способ  ограничить доступ, либо регистрации изменения файлов вне программы

Comment: Программа - ваша самописная?

Comment: Нет, название - stamina, самоучитель  10 пальцевого набора

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос: 1) Добавьте название программы в текст вопроса. 2) Замените термин "печать" на термин "набор текста на клавиатуре".

Comment: *Прошу подсказать способ ограничить доступ* Ограничить кому? к чему? запретить юзеру править/подделывать свои результаты, что ли? Создайте отдельного пользователя с паролем. Запускайте программу от его имени через ярлык с `runas /savecred`. Запретите изменение файла всем, кроме этого пользователя.